# Button disabling while method execution (PreviewLeftMouseDown/Up must be workable)

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a sequence as follows:

- button default state
- button Down, "methods for button Down" execute and Button itself is disabled for a time.
- button is enabled since "Disabling" time is elapsed, button Up, "methods for button Up" execute.
- button default state

I've tried this code and it acts at its first part properly. But second part (Up) does not execute.
Could anyone help me?

```
    private void btn1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
                var btn = (Button)sender;
                btn.IsEnabled = false; //Disable button.
                var fooTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); //Exceute after 5000 milliseconds
                fooTimer.Elapsed += (fooTimer_s, fooTimer_e) =>
                {
                    //It has to be dispatched because of thread crossing if you are using WPF.
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        btn.IsEnabled = true; //Bring button back to life by enabling it.
                        fooTimer.Dispose();
                    });
                };
                fooTimer.Start();

      // methods for button Down go here

    }


    private void btn1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // methods for button Up go here
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this more easily in an async Click handler:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // perform time-consuming action
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // just for test
    });

    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: What about time? And what about other method which are supposed to be executed in "Up" section?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. `await Task.Delay(5000);` instead of Task.Run would disable the Button for 5 seconds.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(5000);` means that the button "freezes" for 5 sec. It's Ok, I need that preset. I don't see such an opportunity In your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you want to disable the Button as long as a time-consuming operation is running, you do of course not need Task.Delay. Just put the long-running code in an awaited Task, as shown here.

Comment: `Just put the long-running code in an awaited Task, as shown here.` What does mean "long-running code"?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you actually want to disable the Button as long as some operation is in progress?

Comment: I want to "freeze" button for approx 3-6 sec. At the same time. PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown/Up must be workable. That's all. In those event i execute methods. These method start other methods "at field". Since there's no opportunity to get a feedback. i just have to set "freezing time" approximately.

Comment: But for what reason? A disable Button won't receive events. What's the purpose? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to "freeze" button for approx 3-6 sec. At the same time PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown/Up must be workable. That's all. In those events I  execute methods. These methods start other methods "at field". Since there's no opportunity to get a feedback. I just have to set "freezing time" approximately.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. As said, a disable Button won't receive events. And you still don't explain why the Button should be disabled at all.

Comment: An execution of methods "at field" requires some time. However, most users have no idea about. So when they're seing that there's a some delay of data receiving they start pushing buttons. The simpliest solution to disable the button.

Comment: Sure, the simplest solution is to disable the Button, then perform the action that takes some time, then enable the Button again. This is exactly what would happen if you'd run that action in an awaited Task - where I have put Thread.Sleep in the example above. Perhaps just try it out.

Comment: It works at first part at the event "Down". When the button becomes enabled the event "Up" doesn't start. I need to set bit to "1" at the event "Down" and set bit "0" at the event  "Up". That's the point.