# Button click event with two methods which execute one after another by timer

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to implement in Button click event two executing one after another methods by timer?
Could anyone suggest something?

Sequence as follows:

- Within button click
- first method execution
- some delay (e.g. 3 sec.)
- second method execution.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean sleep in few seconds?

Comment: I mean when button click event acts, there should be executed methods sequence. Method 1 --> delay --> Method2. Also the delay must be customizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `async` Click event handler with `await Task.Delay`:

```
// class member
private TimeSpan clickActionDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;

    firstAction();

    // wait 3 seconds without blocking the UI thread
    await Task.Delay(clickActionDelay);

    secondAction();

    button.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void firstAction()
{
    ...
}

private void secondAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Clemens, since the "second  part" doesn't work (see my first post here) I'm  going to try that in a single Click. Perhaps that is going to be a solution.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Haven't you tried it?

Comment: I meant this topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754158/button-disabling-while-method-execution-previewleftmousedown-up-must-be-workabl/59754233?noredirect=1#comment105656505_59754233[link] where I used two parts PreviewMouseButtonDown and Up.

Comment: I know that question, since I wrote the answer. What has it got to do with what you are asking here? The questions are totally different. The first one asks how to disable a Button *while a single method is executed*, while this one asks how to put a delay *between the execution of two methods*. Have you at least tried out what I am suggesting here? Are you not observing a delay between the calls of firstAction and secondAction?

Comment: The point is that I'm going to combine "button freezing" from previous question and these two methods execution sequence by timer which are also suggested by you, here.

Comment: So what exactly stops you from disabling the Button before calling firstAction and enabling it after secondAction? See the edited answer.

Comment: I've checked in sample-project your renewed (combined) code, Looks promising. Thanks a lot! You are  man.

Comment: Clemens, frankly speaking I've got only one thing I can't still vote due to having of less 15 reps. As concerned the answer acceptance, I still have no clue where this "check mark" is, beside the answer which is supposed to be accepted. ))) Sorry.

Comment: The check mark is directly below the up-/downvote button at the top left of the answer text.