# WPF check button command or click event is done

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF UserControl contain a button,
I want to when I click on button, button content change to other text and after run command or user click event, button content change to other text.

for example :

1- Button text = click me (before click)

2- Button text = please wait (after click)

3- run user click event Or command

4-Button text = it's done (before click)

I can pass step 1 and 2 using button click event,
also pass step 3 by UserControl ButtonBase.Click event.

I don't know how to pass step 4.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754233/1136211) where you set Content instead of IsEnabled?

Comment: Not exactly, I want instead of `Thread.Sleep(5000)` run user ButtonBase.Click event

Comment: Sure, the Sleep is just a placeholder for a long running operation.